# ReferenceError <component> is not defined but running twice with Laravel 10 and Livewire 3.0

Tags: laravel-blade, vite, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am seeing strange behaviour from an Alpine JS component when running with Laravel 10.20 and Livewire 3.0.0-beta.10. I have a Laravel Blade component that contains an Alpine JS component. The `<script>` is `push`ed to a `stack` in my `app.blade.php`. In the console, I see "Uncaught ReferenceError:  is not defined".

I have created a very basic, contrived Blade (not Livewire) component to demonstrate.

The blade component:

```php
<ul x-data="testApp" x-init='items=@json($items)'>
    <template x-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        <li :idx="index" @click="logItem($event)" x-text="item"></li>
    </template>
</ul>
@once
    @push('scripts')
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
                Alpine.data('testApp', () => ({
                    items: [],
                    init() {
                        console.log('testApp.init()');
                    },
                    logItem(event) {
                        console.log(event.target.innerText);
                    }
                }));
            });
        </script>
    @endpush
@endonce
```

The class for the Blade component has the standard `render()` method and the most basic constructor.

```php
public function __construct(public array $items) {}
```

The `blade` that uses the component:

```php
<x-app-layout>
    <div>
        @php
            $items = ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'];
        @endphp
        <x-test :items="$items" />
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

The route to that blade:

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('member-dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

`app.blade.php`:

```php
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css'])
        @livewireStyles
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        @stack('scripts')
        @vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see that I have even tried splitting the default `@vite` directive, which normally loads the `css` and `js` in the `<head>`. I have also tried the `@vite`, `@stack` and `@livewireScripts` in all possible sequences. None of these has any effect, which, in itself, seems a little odd.

When I load the page, I see the following in the console:

1. the output from the `console.log()` within `testApp.init()`
2. a warning: "Alpine Expression Error: testApp is not defined" from `livewire.js`
3. an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError:  is not defined" from `livewire.js`

On the page, I see the set of three `<li>` elements duplicated within the `<ul>`. That is, I end up with six `<li>` elements:

- Test A
- Test B
- Test C
- Test A
- Test B
- Test C

When I click an item, I see it's `innerText` appear in the console twice. So, clearly, the `testApp` object does exist because its `logItem` method is being called, albeit twice.

This is in a new project that I started, not an upgrade. The same component and approach works fine in a different project with Laravel 9 and Livewire 2.10 (with Alpine JS 3.10) and no Vite.

It is not clear whether the two problems (The Uncaught `ReferenceError` and duplication of data) are caused by the same underlying issue. I have been through the Liverwire and Laravel upgrade documentation and cannot see anything that appears relevant to explain why this would work with older versions but not with the latest. The other potentially major difference is that I using Vite on the new project.

I am using VS Code and Laragon for development on Windows 11.

**UPDATE** 12:06 23-Aug-2023

I noticed that the components that are duplicating output are using `x-for` for their loops. I changed the loop in test blade to use `@foreach` and I stopped getting the duplication of `<li>` elements. Unfortunately, I need to use `x-for` in my actual components. Anyway, I still got the uncaught `ReferenceError` and, bizarrely, clicking on one of the items still logs two entries in the console.

Comment: It's not clear if your components are livewire components or standard blade components: since you have not posted any class, I assume they are standard blade components. I've tested them and they work perfectly for me, I have not noticed any duplication (using x-for) or any error once I have added  `@stack('scripts')`.
Perhaps you should add a few more details, especially the workflow you're using.

Comment: The only quirks noted are: in `<li :x-ref="index" @click="logItem($event)" x-text=item></li>` you cannot define the x-refs dynamically and the *x-text* attribute should be `x-text="item"` (although it seems to work) ****** In `<x-test :items=$items />`  *:items* should be `:items="$items"` (although it seems to work)

Comment: @Pippo, thank you. I have fixed the quirks and updated in the question. The `x-ref` was a badly named attribute from some code I borrowed, and not being used as a proper x-ref. I have renamed it. I have also made it clear that it is not a Livewire component and added, "I am using VS Code and Laragon for development on Windows 11". Is there anything else I should include? Did you see the `ReferenceError`? Also, can you please confirm that you are running with Laravel 10 and Livewire 3.0.

Comment: yes I'm running  Laravel 10 and Livewire. Can you show the route? Do you call a Controller/action or a Livewire component?

Comment: @Pippo, it a simple route to a view. I have added it to the question. As yet, I have not added any Livewire functionality to the project, but I will be doing so later.

Comment: I've asked that because you have added @stack(), @vite() and @livewireX to *app.blade.php*, but that is the default base template if you call a Livewire class from the route. Have you verified that your *member-dashboard* View includes those assets too?

Comment: @Pippo, yes, I have all of the following:
`<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/@vite/client" data-navigate-track="reload"></script><script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/app.js" data-navigate-track="reload"></script>        <!-- Livewire Scripts -->
<script src="/livewire/livewire.js?id=78f6b8d8"   data-csrf="jYhDNQnwTS3wuyrrfIU289gPJ84XPbNKdEdXziXM" data-uri="/livewire/update" data-navigate-once="true"></script>`

Comment: If you use *"view source"* from brrowser can you see your `document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => { Alpine.data('testApp', () => ({.....` ?

Comment: @Pippo, yes that comes immediately after the other `<script>` tags I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problems (and another JavaScript error when collapsing any element using Alpine JS x-show) was caused by an error in my `app.js` file. I had:

```js
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
window.Alpine = Alpine;
Alpine.start();
```

None of which is required with Livewire 3, which bundles Alpine JS.

I have removed it all, and all the errors and duplication of elements have stopped.